# Handling multiple .scala build files for a project

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to figure out how does sbt work. I read sbt online documentation and still have an unanswered question.

How does sbt behave when it discovers multiple .scala files in the < root >/project folder each one containing a Build trait implementation?

I performed experiment and discovered that sbt find this situation correct if there is no interference between the build implementations. I call it "interference" but I have no precise  picture of what are correct and incorrect cases and how multiple Build definitions actually flattened into single sbt project.

Comment: Can you explain what is it that you are looking for? The goal of the question is not very clear. It would help if you told us what you are trying to achieve.